# Set Chart Width to 70%

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, charts

does anyone know how can I set **chart width** to **70%** of the container? I have already set my container width to 100% like this: `container.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);`

This is my codes:

```
                    Chart Chart1= new Chart();
                    Chart1.DataSource = dt;
                    Chart1.Width = 800;
                    Chart1.Height = 490;                  

                    Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
                    Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
                    List<object> List1 = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["STATUS"], new object[] { row["MIN"], row["MAX"], row["25THPERCENTILE"], row["75THPERCENTILE"], row["AVG"], row["50THPRECENTILE"] });

                    //create chartareas
                    ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();
                    ca.AxisX = new Axis();
                    ca.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
                    ca.AxisY = new Axis();
                    ca.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
                    Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(ca);

                    //databind
                    Chart1.DataBind();
                    Chart1.Visible = true;

                    panel.Controls.Add(Chart1);
```

Now currently the chart width is set to pixel. I would like to chart width to be set to **percentage**.

**Question**: How can I set **chart width** to **70%**?

Comment: 70% of what,  is it 70% of`800`  or is it 70% of the page, container, etc?

Comment: hi @Spencer Wieczorek, is 70% of the container. I have already set the container width to 100%. Like this: container.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);, have edited my question thanks!

Comment: if you can get the size of the container, how about doing some calculation: `Chart1.Width = (0.70 * container.Width)`

Comment: hi @Dyrandz Famador, have tried using this method but I get the following error: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit'

Comment: add a suffix `m` in `0.70`.. like this: `Chart1.Width = (0.70m * container.Width)` - _Without the suffix m, the number is treated as a double, thus generating a compiler error_.

Comment: hi @Dyrandz Famador, have tried this too but got another similar error:Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit'

Comment: what is the value of `container.Width`? have you tried to print its value?

Comment: hi @DyrandzFamador, i tried to print its value using container.Width.Value, but 100 appeared. was not able to print value in pixel, i only get back percentage value.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `Chart` control accepts only `UnitType.Pixel`.

This works fine:

```
 Unit unit1 = new Unit(70, UnitType.Pixel);
 Chart1.Width = unit1;
```

But this,

```
 Unit unit2 = new Unit(70, UnitType.Percentage);
 Chart1.Width = unit2;
```

Throws an exception:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
>     HResult=-2147024809
>     Message=**Chart width MUST be set in pixels.**
>     Source=System.Web.DataVisualization
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.set_Width(Unit value)
>          at WebApplication63.WebForm1.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\WebApplication63\WebApplication63\WebForm1.aspx.cs:line 16
>          at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>     InnerException:

Comment: hi jstreet, does this mean that I can only set chart width in pixel? there is no way to set chart width as percentage? thanks for your reply and help!

Comment: @FeliciaSoh, hi, unfortunately that's what it seems.... the exception message couldn't be more clear.

Comment: hi @jstreet, ok understood, thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You can try it on your own and verify it... or maybe someone else might have some other idea but i doubt it.... the code is pretty straightforward and so is the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you specify a client-side Id for the chart and specify the width with css?

```
<asp:Chart ID="myChart" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

And then in your css:

```
#myChart{
    width:70%;
}
```